# Flutter says Brew is not installed

Tags: flutter, dart, homebrew

I have installed homebrew but flutter says it is not installed:

```
iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 9.3, Build version 9E145
✗ Brew not installed; use this to install tools for iOS device development.
  Download brew at https://brew.sh/.
```

`brew --version` prints

```
Homebrew 1.6.3 
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 27e7; last commit 2018-05-11)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @M.Luffy looks good. Doesn't look like you did anything wrong.